# Obj-C - Get first X number of characters after a string inside NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like so:

```
NSString *testing = @"Feb 5 2021 05:00 PM, Feb 6 2021 07:00 PM";
```

That said, I want my code to be able to grab the 8 characters after "Feb 5, 2021" and put them into another string (05:00 PM). Any idea how I can accomplish this? I'm stumped, as I only want it to grab that time, and not the other characters after it.

These dates will also always be different, so I don't want to simply count the number of characters in 'Feb 5 2021' (otherwise, if that count changes by a single character the code won't work lol).

Comment: "so I don't want to simply count the number of characters" I don't get it. Please clarify what precisely are the _knowns_ when the problem begins. Do you in fact know ahead of time that you want exactly 8 characters starting right after the space after the exact substring "Feb 5 2021"? Or is the problem that you want the fourth and fifth "words" whatever and wherever they may be? Or what?

Comment: I would use `componentsSeparatedByString`  (with `",`" separator) to get the different dates. I would transform the 2 strings into `NSDate` objects  (with either a NSDateFormatter if the format is the same, or maybe a `NSDataDetector`) and show the user what's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to solve this. However if the format of the string input is reliable and performance or memory usage is not of a concern:

```
NSString    *testing = @"Feb 5 2021 05:00 PM, Feb 6 2021 07:00 PM";

NSArray     *tokens=[testing componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString    *time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tokens[3],tokens[4]];

NSLog(@"time: %@",time);
```

If you need all the times, and the number of date/time values is variable:

```
NSString    *testing = @"Feb 5 2021 05:00 PM, Feb 6 2021 07:00 PM"; 
NSArray     *datums=[testing componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];

for(NSString *datum in datums)
{
    NSArray     *tokens=[datum componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString    *time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tokens[3],tokens[4]];
    
    NSLog(@"time: %@",time);
}
```

Note you will need additional error checking if the string may be empty or contain invalid data.

Comment: Ahhh I ended up figuring out EXACTLY what I needed based on this answer, thank you so much. It is, indeed, correct :) You rock.

Answer (score 0):

Your input appears to be a list of date-time values in a *fixed* format, i.e. the number of characters in a month or number may change but the overall pattern remains the same.

If this is the case and you only wish to operate at the textual level, i.e. you do not wish to parse the strings to produce `NSDate` values, you can use [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression?language=objc). Construct the pattern for the date-time format using grouping to capture the parts of the date-time you wish to extract, and then use the methods of `NSRegularExpression` to process all the matches in your string.

If you have trouble getting your code to work ask a new question showing what you have produced and describing the issue – someone will undoubtedly help you along.

HTH